# Как указать, между каких элементов будет создаваемый элемент?

Tags: javascript, html

Как в JS задать порядковый номер создаваемого элемента?

```
var MainNavDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('main-navBar-entryPoints')[0];
var newLi = document.createElement("li");
```

И если в конце кода

```
  MainNavDiv.insertBefore(newLi, MainNavDiv.secondElementChild)
```

То он будет последним

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если

```
MainNavDiv.insertBefore(newD, MainNavDiv.firstElementChild)
```

То он будет первым

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но а как его воткнуть между, например, третьим и четвёртым?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде используется несуществующий метод *secondElementChild*, в результате чего второй аргумент метода *insertBefore* равен **undefined**. На сайте [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) этот случай описан следующим образом:

> В Mozilla Firefox, если referenceElement не задан или равен null, newElement вставляется в конец списка дочерних элементов.

В некоторых версиях браузеров результат может быть другим.

Возможный вариант исправления ошибки - использование свойства элемента [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children):

```js
MainNavDiv.insertBefore(newLi, MainNavDiv.children[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Например так.

```js
let li = document.querySelectorAll('#ul li');

let newLi = document.createElement('li');
newLi.style.background = 'red';
newLi.textContent = 'newLi';

li[3].after(newLi);
```

```html
<ul id="ul">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: В моём случае почему то не сработало :c

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'after' of undefined`